# How to build Platinum UPnP stack with Android NDK?

Tags: java, android-ndk, scons, upnp

I have a problem with building the Platinum UPnP stack with Android NDK on MacOSX 10.6.5.

I've downloaded the latest version of Android NDK for Mac from [here](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r5-darwin-x86.tar.bz2), installed SCons (for building) and downloaded the latest version of Platinum form their website.

Than I setup the ANDROID_NDK_HOME to my NDK root directory and tried to build:
*scons -Q target=arm-android-linux* and I got the following error:

> (...)
>   Exception: ANDROID NDK not configured, use host-setup.sh to configure it:
>   (...)

The problem is that this file got removed from the Android NDK according to the documentation:

> Previous releases required you to run the 'build/host-setup.sh' script to
>   configure the NDK. However, this step has been removed in release 4.

And now I'm kinda stuck and don't know how to solve this issue.

UPDATE:

I've downloaded the NDK r3 (the last one with the missing file) and configured it with host-setup.sh

But when I try to build the target, it runs for some time and then crashes on:

```
Build/Targets/arm-android-linux/Debug/Source/Tests/FileMediaServer/FileMediaServerTest.o: In function `main':
/Users/darkh/Platinum-SRC-0-6-3_683/Platinum/Source/Tests/FileMediaServer/FileMediaServerTest.cpp:153: warning: warning: gets() is very unsafe; consider using fgets()

Build/Targets/arm-android-linux/Debug/libPltMediaServer.a(PltMediaItem.o): In function `PLT_MediaItem::DynamicCast(void const*)':
PltMediaItem.cpp:(.text._ZN13PLT_MediaItem11DynamicCastEPKv[PLT_MediaItem::DynamicCast(void const*)]+0x5c): undefined reference to `PLT_MediaItem::_class_PLT_MediaItem'

Build/Targets/arm-android-linux/Debug/libPltMediaServer.a(PltMediaItem.o): In function `PLT_MediaContainer::DynamicCast(void const*)':
PltMediaItem.cpp:(.text._ZN18PLT_MediaContainer11DynamicCastEPKv[PLT_MediaContainer::DynamicCast(void const*)]+0x5c): undefined reference to `PLT_MediaContainer::_class_PLT_MediaContainer'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

scons: *** [Build/Targets/arm-android-linux/Debug/FileMediaServerTest] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the host-setup.sh issue, it looks like Platinum uses its own SCons based build system that relies on the path of the compiler containing arm-eabi-4.4.0. That has changed in the latest Android NDK too.

You'll either have to hack the build system yourself or wait for them to update it for r5. A good place to start looking would be the file `Build/Targets/arm-android-linux/Config.scons`, but there are quite a few non-obvious changes you'd have to make to get it up and running.

EDIT:

Try with r4b. Create a file in `android-ndk-r4b/out/host/config.mk` whose contents is:

```
HOST_TAG := linux-x86
```

.. or the equivalent on Mac - whatever the directory in `android-ndk-r4b/build/prebuilt/` is called. That should compile the lot - it did here.

Comment: I've downloaded the NDK r3 (the last one with the host-setup.sh) and configured it. I was able to make it running but after some time I got an error.

Comment: I've edited the Config.scons manually and made the line with host tag static. 
I've managed to compile it with r4b a bit but got the error that I mentioned in the main post again.
Build/Targets/arm-android-linux/Debug/libPltMediaServer.a(PltMediaItem.o): In function `PLT_MediaItem::DynamicCast(void const*)':
/Users/darkh/Platinum-SRC-0-6-3_683/Platinum/Source/Devices/MediaServer/PltMediaItem.h:244: undefined reference to `PLT_MediaItem::_class_PLT_MediaItem'

Comment: @darkhie - uf, no idea then. Maybe a "scons -c" to clean out previous build crud? Failing that, I think the platinum mailing list is going to be your best bet :-(

Comment: I've contacted the creator and he released a new version of platinum that fixed the build error :) With the change in the Config.scons (the host tag thing) and and NDK r4b I was able to make a successful build :)